# Document level lock in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is document level lock possible in mongodb 3.4?

My collection contains millions of documents. I have scenario where I want to delete some documents (based on some id criteria) in the collection, and while these documents are being deleted, they should not be accessible by other users.

The documents which I do not want to delete should be accessible by other users.

So, I want to lock a few documents (based on some id criteria) which I want to delete.

Or is there a another way to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger storage engine is the default storage engine.

WiredTiger uses document-level concurrency control for write operations. As a result, multiple clients can modify different documents of a collection at the same time.

db.collection.remove() supports multi-document transactions.

so I think using default write concern should be enough for you.

More reference can be found at [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

Comment: suppose i want to remove 10 million documents( out of my 30 millions documents in a collection) , so while these documents are being deleted i do not want these 10 million documets to get accessed by an other thread while rest 20 million should be accessible

Comment: This is the same what happens by default. You can re-check by a POC.

Comment: Can you share with me the POC you did. I need to check.